# React native on navigation app is crashed error android::Thread::_threadLoop

Tags: android, react-native, navigation

React native app is crashing on navigation event, the screen that crashes is depending on id the, id from param is used to call api, the api data is using in Webview. it some time crashes otherwise work fine,

I am sharing link that may help to find issue.
https://sentry.io/share/issue/66198bd33cc74911bd5b242f91d918c8/